# Liferay Asset-Publisher Configuration is broken

Tags: jsp, view, configuration, liferay

Liferay 6.1.1 ce ga2

Hi all,

sometimes, when my customer changes the configuration of the asset publisher, it gets broken=> its not visible anymore!

[image: empty configuration of asset-publihser]

And what are these random characters?

[image]

I think the configuration.jsp inside of asset_publisher portlet is somehow broken? I didnt touch it!

thanks in advance!

Comment: crossreferencing https://www.liferay.com/en/c/message_boards/find_message?messageId=25319498 , waiting for your input there. It looks like you've customized the configuration

Comment: the cross-referenced thread is non-English, so I hope you'll answer the question here and share the solution with us

Comment: we discuss the issue in german in the other forum, but I will post everything that might help into stackoverflow too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was another web-content-display portlet, where I dirtily embedded a flash-application.
I had to write an own simple portlet for that. It simply puts the embed code in the portlet-view. Works!
So, what I learned is: When you want to use embed-codes, you must write a simple portlet for that.
hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 1):

Do you set google analytics in your portal?
Please check this post:
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/25503275
Hope it can resolve your problem.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Hi thanks for the cool link! I solved the main problem, but the strange strings in the screenshots remain. I will check for google analytics the next days.